# Asp.net..Issue with image control and literal control

Tags: asp.net

this line..here in image control `src` attritbute..the requried image page is not called..

```
ltrlMessage.Text = "<p><table><tr><td width='5%' valign=top><img ID='imgmsg1' runat='server' src = 'DRSS_Msglogo.aspx' /><td Class='labelcss'>" + listAbsWelcomeMessage[0].MBMessage.Trim() + "</td> </tr><tr><td colspan='2'> </td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' Class='labelcss'> " + msg + "</td><td width=2px></td></tr></table></p>";
```

Comment: "ltrlMessage.Text = "<p><table><tr><td width='5%'  valign=top><img ID='imgmsg1' runat='server' src = 'DRSS_Msglogo.aspx' /><td  Class='labelcss'>" + listAbsWelcomeMessage[0].MBMessage.Trim() + "</td> </tr><tr><td colspan='2'> </td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' Class='labelcss'> " + msg + "</td><td width=2px></td></tr></table></p>";"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your image source path will be wrong.Please test with following code.

```
ltrlMessage.Text = "<p><table><tr><td width='5%' valign=top><img ID='imgmsg1' runat='server' src = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/128ce87fc5638cbc75f7425664686b5f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG' /><td Class='labelcss'>" + listAbsWelcomeMessage[0].MBMessage.Trim() + "</td> </tr><tr><td colspan='2'> </td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' Class='labelcss'> " + msg + "</td><td width=2px></td></tr></table></p>";
```

Comment: let me check it..vl let u knw

Comment: src='../../DRSS_CommonImages/messageboardicon_tran.gif' using dis is working fine.but this is like hardcoding the image

Comment: if u want to make it dynamic.put inside variable                   src='"+ variable +"'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call another page within your page use iframe tag instead of img tag:

```
<iframe src="DRSS_Msglogo.aspx"></iframe>
```

instead of:

```
<img ID='imgmsg1' src ='DRSS_Msglogo.aspx' />
```

Comment: its like..the image would be upload in database and by calling in this page that dynamically uploaded images gets called from database..this line works fine in my other project.giving issuse only in this current page.